# Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type C++

Tags: c++

```
   using namespace std;

   void game();

int party_rnd(int &party_members)
{
    char roll_party;

    cout << "Please [R]oll the dice to decide how many will dare enter with you.\n";

    cin >> roll_party;

    if (roll_party == 'R') {
        srand(time(NULL));
        party_members = rand() % 6 + 1;
        cout << "You have been joined by " << party_members << " of your friends!\n\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "\nYou can't not roll!\n";
        system("Pause");
        system("cls");
        game();
    }

    return 0;
}

string party_name(int &party_members, string (&party_names))
{
    string* party_name = new string[party_members];
    for (int i = 0; i < party_members; i++) {
        cout << "Please enter a name for your party member: ";
        cin >> party_name[i];
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "Your party consists of: ";
    cout << endl;

    for (int x = 0; x < party_members; x++) {
        cout << party_name[x] << "\n";
    }

    return *party_name;
}

void game()
{
    system("cls");

    int party_members = 0;
    string* party_names = new string[party_members];

    cout << "Welcome to Professor Scott and the Temple of Doom!\n";
    cout << "Before you can enter you must roll a dice to see how many of your friends will follow you!\n\n";

    party_rnd(party_members);

    party_name(party_members, party_names[party_members]);

    for (int y = 0; y < party_members; y++) {
        cout << party_name[y] << "\n";
    }

    return;
}
```

Im getting an error at line 67 "cout << party_name[x] << "\n";" expression must be a pointer to a complete object type. Any help would be great as I am quite new to C++ and am not sure what exactly is wrong with the code. I have googled a fair bit but nothing has really made sense as to why I am not able to get the string array passed back correctly.

Comment: try party_name->at(x).

Comment: Im sorry I don't really follow what you mean by that. Do you mean replacing line 67 with that or what could you give a bit more detail?

Comment: `party_name` is a function. You cannot do `[y]` on the name of a function. Also your `party_name` function has several major problems. To fix this you should represent a list of names by `vector<string>` instead of using pointers and new. Also, it is more natural to use the return value of a function to return values, instead of using reference parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void game();

int party_rnd(int &party_members)
{
char roll_party;

cout << "Please [R]oll the dice to decide how many will dare enter with you.\n";

cin >> roll_party;

if (roll_party == 'R') {
    srand(time(NULL));
    party_members = rand() % 6 + 1;
    cout << "You have been joined by " << party_members << " of your friends!\n\n";
}
else {
    cout << "\nYou can't not roll!\n";
    system("Pause");
    system("cls");
    game();
}

return 0;
}

string party_name(int &party_members, string (&party_names))
{
string* party_name = new string[party_members];
for (int i = 0; i < party_members; i++) {
    cout << "Please enter a name for your party member: ";
    cin >> party_name[i];
    cout << endl;
}

cout << "Your party consists of: ";
cout << endl;

for (int x = 0; x < party_members; x++) {
    cout << party_name[x] << "\n";
}

return *party_name;
}

void game()
{
system("cls");

int party_members = 0;
string* party_names = new string[party_members];

cout << "Welcome to Professor Scott and the Temple of Doom!\n";
cout << "Before you can enter you must roll a dice to see how many of your friends will follow you!\n\n";

party_rnd(party_members);

party_name(party_members, party_names[party_members]);

for (int y = 0; y < party_members; y++) {
    cout << party_names[y] << "\n";
}

return;
}
```

I could get the above code to compile. Check here: 
[changed-code](http://ideone.com/1Nc1jF)